# how to add template file in rspec-puppet

Tags: rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

I have below manifests for sudo user, loading template file

```
class sudo {
  if $::operatingsystemmajrelease < 7 {
    $variable = $::operatingsystemmajrelease ? {
      '6' => $::fqdn,

    }
    file { '/etc/sudoers' :
      ensure  => present,
      owner   => 'root',
      group   => 'root',
      mode    => '0440',
      content => template('sudo/sudoers.erb'),
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my rspec file

```
vim test_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'sudo' do
  it { should contain_class('sudo')}
  let(:facts) {{:operatingsystemmajrelease => 6}}

  if (6 < 7)
    context "testing sudo template with rspec" do
    let(:params) {{:content => template('sudo/sudoers.erb')}}
    it {should contain_file('/etc/sudoers').with(
      'ensure' => 'present',
      'owner'   => 'root',
      'group'   => 'root',
      'mode'    => '0440',
      'content' => template('sudo/sudoers.erb'))}
  end
  end
end
```

getting below error when run "rake spec"

```
.F
Failures:
  1) sudo testing sudo template with rspec
     Failure/Error: 'content' => template('sudo/sudoers.erb'))}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `template' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x7f5802e70bd8>
     # ./spec/classes/test_spec.rb:17
Finished in 0.16067 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/classes/test_spec.rb:12 # sudo testing sudo template with rspec
rake aborted!
ruby -S rspec spec/classes/test_spec.rb failed
```

Can any one guide me how  to test template with rspec-puppet. I surfed net also breaking my head more than two days none helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`template` is a function of the Puppet parser and as such is not available to your unit tests.

If you **really** want to use your existing template as a fixture, you will have to have to [manually](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new-label-Example) evaluate its ERB code.

The much better unit testing approach would be to hard-code test data right in the test code.

```
if (6 < 7)
  context "testing sudo template with rspec" do
  let(:params) {{:content => 'SPEC-CONTENT'}}
  it {should contain_file('/etc/sudoers').with(
    'ensure' => 'present',
    'owner'   => 'root',
    'group'   => 'root',
    'mode'    => '0440',
    'content' => 'SPEC-CONTENT'}
  end
end
```

Using actual valid templates is more interesting in the realms of acceptance or perhaps integration testing.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried without let(:params) but it worked. Do we need to create with params for this case.

Comment: @Puppeteer I don't follow, I'm afraid.

Comment: Below is my spec file without param, "describe 'sudo' do it { should contain_class('sudo')} let(:facts) {{:operatingsystemmajrelease => 6}} if (6 < 7) context "testing sudo template with rspec" do it {should contain_file('/etc/sudoers').with( 'ensure' => 'present', 'owner' => 'root', 'group' => 'root', 'mode' => '0440')} it {should contain_file('/etc/sudoers').with_content( /Defaults requiretty/) } end end end"

Comment: I actually wanted to not ask but - why `if ( 6 < 7)`? Do you realize that this is always false? That the code never actually **runs**? Sure, your test compiles now, but I don't think it works at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to either give a string or regex for content:

```
 context 'with compress => true' do
    let(:params) { {:compress => true} }

    it do
      should contain_file('/etc/logrotate.d/nginx') \
        .with_content(/^\s*compress$/)
    end
  end

  context 'with compress => false' do
    let(:params) { {:compress => false} }

    it do
      should contain_file('/etc/logrotate.d/nginx') \
        .with_content(/^\s*nocompress$/)
    end
  end
```

Full description of it here: http://rspec-puppet.com/tutorial/

Comment: I tried, getting "1) sudo testing sudo template with rspec Failure/Error: 'mode' => '0440')} Puppet::Error: Invalid parameter compress on Class[Sudo] at line 4 on node # ./spec/classes/test_spec.rb:16 2) sudo testing sudo template with rspec Failure/Error: it do should contain_file('/etc/sudoers').with_content(/^\s*compress$/) Puppet::Error: Invalid parameter compress on Class[Sudo] at line 4 on node # ./spec/classes/test_spec.rb:20" error. Is it not possible to load template file in rspec-puppet, becuase in my manifests used loading erb file for facts. so i want to test with loading template.